# s3->GCS access denied error

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to transfer files from s3-gcs.

I don't own the s3 bucket and was provided with keys.

I edited my boto and entered the key & access id's but my gsutil cp command returned an access denied error. I can browse/dl these files with the various free s3 browser utilities out there.

Might the owner need to adjust something on their end?

```
    gsutil cp -r s3://origin gs://destination
    Copying s3://origin
    17/_SUCCESS [Content-Type=binary/octet-stream]...
    Exception in thread Thread-2: B]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-
    sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/daisy_chain_wrapper.py", line 196, in 
    PerformDownload
    decryption_tuple=self.decryption_tuple)
    File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-
    sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/cloud_api_delegator.py", line 276, in 
    GetObjectMedia
    decryption_tuple=decryption_tuple)
    File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/boto_translation.py", 
    line 513, in GetObjectMedia
    generation=generation)
     File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/boto_translation.py", 
     line 1476, in _TranslateExceptionAndRaise
    raise translated_exception
    AccessDeniedException: AccessDeniedException: 403 AccessDenied
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>DD4EA91291B40907</RequestId>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your SSH session, check what account is activated on the instance.

```
$ gcloud auth list
```

Then try using the `-D` or `-DD` command line options to debug why your example is failing. And you can try running `gsutil` with the top-level `-D` flag.

1) To copy from S3 to local disk

```
gsutil -D cp -r s3://secret-bucket/some_key/    /local/directory/my-s3-files/
```

2) To copy from local disk to GCS bucket

```
gsutil -D cp -r /local/directory/my-s3-files/     gs://secret-elsewhere/destination/
```

You can check [Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/) article to how transfer data into Cloud Storage.

We have to make sure permission error is in GCP or S3. Also, you can have a look at these articles for more information:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/487
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp

Comment: Thanks so much!  The decoding seems to indicate that permission issue is on the S3 side.  I also realized that I can successfully list the files in the S3... just not download them.  The transfer service also returns a permissions error.