# Access Denied when copying Amazon S3 files using gsutil - fine using aws s3 cp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gcloud, gsutil

Similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48329533/s3-gcs-access-denied-error) here I'm getting Access Denied when trying to copy files from an Amazon S3 bucket to a Google Storage bucket.

I've also broken it down into two parts, copying from S3 > local machine - which also fails. hen I run `gsutil -D cp s3://my-bucket/filename.txt ./test-copy` I get the following:

```
    gslib.cloud_api.AccessDeniedException: AccessDeniedException: 403 AccessDenied
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>**REDACTED**</RequestId><HostId>**REDACTED**bc=</HostId></Error>
```

What I've tried:

- Using a different AWS Access key (with full AWS permissions to the S3 bucket for overkill!)
- When I run `aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/filename.txt ./test-copy` it works fine, so definitely no permissions issues on AWS
- Checked the gcloud config I'm using - which is the correct one with and checked permissions to the Google Cloud storage bucket (added on Storage Admin for overkill)

The fact than I can copy using `aws s3 cp` confirms the AWS access key I'm using has permissions to copy from that S3 bucket. It feels to me like an issue with python/gsutil, the versions on my laptop:

- gsutil version: 5.20
- Python 3.10.8

Here's more of the DEBUG log snippet if it helps:

```
Zero length chunk ignored
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n'
header: x-amz-request-id: **REDACTED**
header: x-amz-id-2: **REDACTED**
header: Content-Type: application/xml
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Date: Tue, 07 Mar 2023 15:35:40 GMT
header: Server: AmazonS3
DEBUG 0307 15:35:41.384847 connection.py] Response headers: [('x-amz-request-id', '**REDACTED**'), ('x-amz-id-2', '**REDACTED**'), ('Content-Type', 'application/xml'), ('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked'), ('Date', 'Tue, 07 Mar 2023 15:35:40 GMT'), ('Server', 'AmazonS3')]
DEBUG: Exception stack trace:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/**REDACTED**/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/boto_translation.py", line 718, in _PerformResumableDownload
        key.get_file(fp,
    TypeError: Key.get_file() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hash_algs'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/**REDACTED**/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/boto_translation.py", line 590, in GetObjectMedia
        self._PerformResumableDownload(download_stream,
      File "/Users/**REDACTED**/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/boto_translation.py", line 725, in _PerformResumableDownload
        key.get_file(fp,
      File "/Users/**REDACTED**/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/vendored/boto/boto/s3/key.py", line 1500, in get_file
        self._get_file_internal(fp, headers=headers, cb=cb, num_cb=num_cb,
      File "/Users/**REDACTED**/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/vendored/boto/boto/s3/key.py", line 1536, in _get_file_internal
        self.open('r', headers, query_args=query_args,
      File "/Users/**REDACTED**/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/vendored/boto/boto/s3/key.py", line 357, in open
        self.open_read(headers=headers, query_args=query_args,
      File "/Users/**REDACTED**/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/vendored/boto/boto/s3/key.py", line 317, in open_read
        raise provider.storage_response_error(self.resp.status,
    boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>**REDACTED**</RequestId><HostId>**REDACTED**</HostId></Error>
```

Comment: "The fact than I can copy using aws s3 cp confirms the AWS access key I'm using has permissions to copy from that S3 bucket" agreed.  Unless you're not providing those credentials properly to gsutil.  Why not just use `aws s3` along with `gsutil`?

Comment: I didn’t think I could copy direct to a google cloud storage bucket using aws s3, but to be fair I haven’t tried it in a while.

Comment: @erik258 yep aws s3 cp works! Could have sworn it didn't before... never mind.

Comment: In what region the S3 bucket is deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got this to work when I came across this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437769/copying-directly-from-s3-to-google-cloud-storage), and realised that it's likely that the .boto config on the github runner (and also my local config) isn't set up correctly. Locally it's possible to edit ~/.boto manually and add the values in so that gsutil knows what to use e.g.:

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = {KEY_ID}
aws_secret_access_key = {SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
```

but the one I found useful in my github action is to prefix the `gsutil` command:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXXX AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=YYYYYYYY gsutil -m cp s3://bucket-name/filename gs://bucket-name
```

More details on googles official docs here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-gsutil